# Automatically log in a user once after connecting to a domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, active-directory

I am using a script to connect 140+ workstations to a domain.  These workstations are primarily Windows 7 but there are a few XP stations thrown into the mix.  They were previously part of a workgroup and users logged in locally.  I would like to automatically log in a domain user to the workstation when it has been added to the domain so that a user profile is created, then copy items from the old profile to the new using a script.  The copy part is no problem, it's the single logon that is giving me fits.  Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same registry key where you set the automatic logon user name, password, etc.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

You can set a value called `AutoLogonCount`, a REG_DWORD. This specifies the number of times that the computer will login automatically. Each time the machine logs in, the value is decremented. Once it reaches zero (0), the automatic logon stops.